# Retrain Vgg16 keras model on imagenet data set for 1000 classes giving less accuracy on pretrained weight

Tags: python, keras, classification, vgg-net, imagenet

I am using Vgg16 keras model with imagent data set on pre-trained weights as per Keras documentation.
I am trying to replicate results mention in keras documents.But while training it is showing 1% accuracy on below code.How can I replicate similar reults as per Keras Documentation.**Note: This is not fine tuning,I am simply trying to replicate similar result in few epochs on 1000 class of imagenet dataset.**

```
model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=True)
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory="/home/svarada2/Downloads/ILSVRC2012_img_train",
    target_size=(224, 224),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=True,
    seed=42
)

STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit_generator(generator=train_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,

                    epochs=10
)
```